# API having more rights than a 0 rep user.

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, api, reputation

The fact that the API has `total_upvotes` and `total_downvotes` makes the fact that you need 1000 rep on the sites a bit weird. Are there more things that the API knows by default, which you can only acquire by looking at the standard page by having some reputation?

Comment: I just *knew* someone would ask this eventually.

Comment: but don't you need those in the API to calculate the total votes?

Comment: no, api has a "score", which is the total votes count

Comment: Sure, it's a bit weird, but I think it should remain this way. If a <1000 rep user wants the info, they'll have to use the API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

v1 of the API lacks user auth, so such restrictions are unenforceable.

We'd have to deny it to everyone (and arguably, a large percentage of the end-users of the API are going to be over that rep limit) which, to me, would be kind of overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Checking the [reputation rights list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow) it seems that the reduced advertising (well, technically the API could have put ad links into the result) is the only thing besides the updown count where the API is "better".

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is timeline for any users, that can see up/down votes as well.

https://stackapps.com/posts/551/timeline

Comment: +1 for making me aware of this currently [somewhat hidden feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/14643) ;)